# Password Salting

Tags: c#, encryption

Is there a security benefit to having an application wide salt as well as a salt that is specific to each user? So when the one way hash is computed the two salts are combined (the one from users database record and the one that is compiled into the applications code).

This way if the database is compromised the attacker wont have all of the information needed to try and crack the passwords.

Comment: yes. it is called pepper :-) https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3272

Comment: 1. No, when the attacker gets admin access to your system he will also get the pepper. You must assume the attacker will gain admin level access 2. The secure way is to iterate a substantial amount of time to increase the work required to create by the attacker to brute force the hash.

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt and pepper does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Better yet use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: ^yeah. if the *database is compromised*, not if the application (or the whole storage) is accessible.

Comment: One needs to assume the worst case: admin access., Just protecting against a subset of attacker is not secure. The current practice is as in my above comment. A pepper does not add the necessary level of security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with BCrypt in the end, thanks for the help guys.